# Deterministic python generator for K disparate M-sized subsets of a set

Tags: python, numpy, generator

I'm looking for an efficient way to generate many M-sized subsets from a set S, of size N.

Ideally I would like to generate all of these, but because I'm using them for other computations, this becomes infeasible.

Instead, I would like to generate K disparate subsets of S, such that the K chosen subsets minimize the sum of the size of the all pairwise intersections between the K subsets.

In other words If I have K subsets
And I take the pairwise intersection of all of those subsets. 
And then I sum the size of all of those sets together. 
I get as low of a number as I can.

Basically, I want these subsets to be as "far away" from each other was possible. 
I've been trying to think of how I would go about doing this, but I'm drawing a blank.

To simulate it in the meantime I've written this function

```
        def subset_split(full_set, M, K):
            np.random.seed(0) # repeatibility
            seen = set([])
            subset_list = []
            for kx in xrange(K):
                np.random.shuffle(full_set)
                failsafe = 0
                while True: 
                    np.random.shuffle(full_set)
                    subset = tuple(full_set[0:M])
                    if not subset in seen: 
                        seen.add(subset)
                        subset_list.append(subset)
                        break
                    failsafe += 1
                    if failsafe > 100:
                        break
            return subset_list
```

which just generates K random subsets that haven't been seen before. But this isn't exactly what I want, because I want those K subsets to be repeatable and to not accidentally be close to each if they don't have to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, **I'm** still having fun with this ;-)

Where this left off, it became clear that we're trying to minimize:

```
sum(n*(n-1)//2 for n in index2count.values())
```

That's minimal if all the values are the same (when possible), or there are two distinct values one apart (like, if `len(full_set) = 10`, seven 3's and three 4's).  That's enough to write a generator that doesn't bother to compute `index2count` at all.  Instead `hi` is the set of indices with the larger of the two values, and `lo` the rest of the indices (`lo` is empty if all the (conceptual! not computed) values are the same).

This drops the `K` argument, and takes a different approach to duplicates:  it ignores them.  It's expensive and clumsy to keep track of duplicates here, and duplicates should really be **expected** in a "random-ish" generator.  If that bothers you, wrap it in another routine to weed out duplicates.

Sample output:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> for s in islice(gen_subsets_special(set(range(5)), 1), 10):
...    print s
set([4])
set([3])
set([0])
set([1])
set([2])
set([0])
set([3])
set([1])
set([2])
set([4])

>>> for s in islice(gen_subsets_special(set(range(10, 20)), 3), 10):
...    print s
set([17, 18, 10])
set([11, 12, 14])
set([16, 19, 13])
set([12, 13, 15])
set([17, 10, 11])
set([16, 19, 15])
set([17, 18, 14])
set([16, 18, 13])
set([19, 12, 15])
set([10, 11, 14])
```

Here's the code:

```
def gen_subsets_special(full_set, M, seed=123456):
    # generate randomish M-subsets of full_set, "far apart".
    import random
    from random import sample
    random.seed(seed)
    elements = list(full_set)
    N = len(elements)
    hi = set(range(N))
    lo = set()
    while True:
        assert not (hi & lo)
        assert len(lo | hi) == N
        # First take indices from hi, then (if needed) from lo.
        if len(hi) > M:
            # We can take all of them from hi, with some left over.
            ixhi = set(sample(hi, M))
            ixlo = set()
            # The ixhi counts go down by 1, so move 'em to lo
            hi -= ixhi
            lo |= ixhi
            assert hi
        else:
            # We need to take everything in hi.
            ixhi = hi.copy()
            ixlo = set(sample(lo, M - len(ixhi)))
            hi |= lo - ixlo
            lo = ixlo
        assert not (ixlo & ixhi)
        ix = ixlo | ixhi
        assert len(ix) == M
        yield set(elements[i] for i in ix)
```

By construction, every prefix of the generated sequence minimizes the sum of the sizes of the intersections of all pairs of sets in the prefix.  Or so it seems to me right now ;-)

Finally, a variation that more obviously just repeatedly cycles thru all the indices.  This is probably the one I'd actually use:

```
def gen_subsets_special(full_set, M, seed=123456):
    # generate randomish M-subsets of full_set, "far apart".
    import random
    from random import sample
    random.seed(seed)
    elements = list(full_set)
    allix = set(range(len(elements)))
    takefrom = allix.copy()

    def destructive_sample(n):
        # Remove a random n-subset from takefrom, & return it.
        s = set(sample(takefrom, n))
        takefrom.difference_update(s)
        return s

    while True:
        if len(takefrom) >= M:
            # Get everything from takefrom.
            ix = destructive_sample(M)
        else:
            # We need to take all of takefrom, and more.
            ix = takefrom
            takefrom = allix - ix
            ix |= destructive_sample(M - len(ix))
        assert len(ix) == M
        yield set(elements[i] for i in ix)
```

Comment: I truly appreciate these responses. I've just been preoccupied for the past 2 days. I suspected that this problem may be hard. I think gen_subsets_special will work perfectly for what I need it for (generating test/train sets for cross validation). On a side note: are you the import this Tim Peters?

Comment: Yup, that's me - I'm old, but new to this site, so "upvote" my answers - LOL ;-)

Hope the code is helpful!  If I can clarify anything, just ask.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a hard problem.  Here's a pragmatic approach:  keep track of how many times each element of `full_set` has been returned, and strive to generate the next subset using the "least popular" (so far) elements.  For example, the code below produces:

```
>>> for s in gen_subsets_special(set(range(5)), 1, 20):
>>>    print s
set([0])
set([1])
set([2])
set([3])
set([4])
```

So it generates each of the 5 possibilities exactly once, and instead of producing 20 of 'em, just quits (it knows there are no other possibilities).  The code can easily be changed to raise an exception if K > N-choose-M.

A more interesting example:

```
>>> for s in gen_subsets_special(set(range(10, 20)), 3, 10):
>>>     print s
set([10, 11, 12])
set([13, 14, 15])
set([16, 17, 18])
set([11, 10, 19])
set([12, 13, 14])
set([16, 17, 15])
set([18, 19, 10])
set([11, 12, 13])
set([16, 14, 15])
set([17, 18, 19])
```

So at least it generates non-overlapping subsets until that becomes impossible ;-)

Here's the code.  It's plain Python (2.7.5), using no numpy features.  It would be more idiomatic **not** to pass K as an argument - the number of items a generator produces is usually controlled by the caller (when the caller is done, it just stops resuming the generator).

```
def gen_subsets_special(full_set, M, K):
    # generate K M-subsets of full_set, "far apart".
    from itertools import combinations
    elements = list(full_set)
    # index2count[i] = # of returned subsets containing
    # elements[i]
    index2count = dict((i, 0) for i in range(len(elements)))
    seen = set()
    for _ in xrange(K):
        bycount = sorted(index2count, key=index2count.get)
        # the least popular indices are at the start;
        # combinations generates results in lexicographic
        # index order, so will return combinations containing
        # the least popular indices first
        for raw in combinations(bycount, M):
            raw = tuple(sorted(raw)) # normalize
            if raw not in seen:
                break
        else:
            # all M-combinations have already been seen
            return
        seen.add(raw)
        for i in raw:
            index2count[i] += 1
        yield set(elements[i] for i in raw)
```

Note that whether the sequence produced is repeatable depends crucially on `list(full_set)` returning the same list each time you run this.  But there's no defined order in which the elements of a set appear.  If set elements support comparison, you can get repeatability by using

```
    elements = sorted(full_set)
```

instead.

Later:  note that the sum of the size of the intersections of all distinct pairs of returned subsets can be computed easily from the `index2count` vector:  it's

```
sum(n*(n-1)//2 for n in index2count.values())
```

Clear?  If a given element appears in exactly `n` of the subsets, then there are n-choose-2 (= n*(n-1)/2) pairs of subsets for which that element is in their intersection, so that element contributes n-choose-2 to the total count.  That's a more formal reason for why striving to balance the counts is helpful here.